# How to access stored user data in django?

Tags: django, session, session-cookies, session-storage

I'm new to django, especially the storing of user data. Basically, I want to save user data searches. They put in a query into a search_bar and I want to save that query. I'm trying to create a list for each user with their search queries at user['search'] and the results of these queries at user['results']. However, I added some code and it does not seem to save the results.

Here is my code for user['results']. It's the same as for user['search']. I'm trying to save the query results by using request.session['result'] = query_result. The reason the results are not obvious is that they make a few choices between entering the query and seeing results.

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
request.session.modified = True
    object_save = list(_objs.values('service__code'))
    if not 'result' in request.session or not request.session['result']:
        renderequest.session['result'] = [object_save]
        request.session.save()
    else:
        result_list = request.session['result']
        result_list.append(object_save)
        request.session['result'] = result_list
        request.session.save()
```

I'd expect this to be able to save and I can look at the searches in python manage.py shell.

When I try to pull all the session data with s = Session.object.get(pk='pk') and s['result'] I get nothing. s has no attribute 'result' is the error.

Maybe I'm completely not understanding user sessions, please help.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Where are you doing `s = Session.object.get(pk='pk')`, and more to the point, why? You should access sessions in the same way you store them, via `request.session`.

Comment: I'm trying to build a database of user searches and results to improve my search functionality, so I want them saved and to be able to work with the data later outside of the running application.